# Can I compose two file paths without needing their toString() methods?

Tags: java, file, path, directory

Imagine I have a 'base' path object, denoting a directory, and a 'relative' path object denoting some file within the base.

I would expect that code to look somewhat like

```
AbsolutePath base = new AbsolutePath("/tmp/adirectory");
RelativePath relativeFilePath = new RelativePath("filex.txt");
AbsolutePath absoluteFile = base.append( relativeFilePath );
```

But in the Java API (which I don't yet know very well) I find only `File`, with which I can do nothing better than

```
File base = new File("/tmp/adirectory");
File relativeFilePath = new File("filex.txt");
File absoluteFile = base.toString() 
                  + File.separator 
                  + relativeFilePath.toString();
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest you can get with [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is [the `File(File, String)` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
File base = ...;
File relative = ...;
File combined = new File(base, relative.toString());
```

If you can use the [`Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class introduced in Java 7, then you can use [the `resolve()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.nio.file.Path%29), which does exactly what you want:

```
Path base = ...;
Path relative = ...;
Path combined = base.resolve(relative);
```

Please note that if `base` is not an absolute path, then `combined` won't be absolute either! If you need an absolute path, then for a `File` you'd use [`getAbsoluteFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29) and for a `Path` you'd use [`toAbsoutePath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [`new File(base, "filex.txt")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) will create a file names "filex.txt" in the directory base.

There is no need to create a `relativeFilePath` File instance with just the relative name if what you want to do is make it relative to another directory than the current one.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
File base = new File("/tmp/adirectory");
File absoluteFile = new File(base, "filex.txt");
```

EDIT: Too late @JB Nizet pipped me at the post...

Answer (score 1):

The File class has some constructors which may be of interest to you:

```
File base = new File("/tmp/adirectory");
File absolute = new File(base, "filex.txt");
File absolute2 = new File("/tmp/adirectory", "filex.txt");
```